# Embed pdf file in html, and allow for download

Tags: html, css

I want to include a small pdf file inside a HTML page. The tricky part is: I dont want to include it as a link, but the complete binary. So the html file will have binary for that pdf. I just want to have a download button which will allow me to download the pdf file out of that html file. Yes, I want all the content to be in one single html file.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: `<a href="path to pdf file">Download PDF</a>`.

Comment: Sorry @Oded, but thats not what I want. I wanted that PDF 'inside' the HTML page

Comment: Please be a lot clearer in your questions - the question is ambiguous.

Comment: Will try to be from next time. I honestly thought I was very clear, but on a rethought I think I was probably a little convoluted while presenting the question. Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode as base64 and use [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to embed inline.

Comment: Thanks, I thought base64 encoding could be only used with JPG files